# Flash stops my mouseover event at edge of embedded button

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, image, image-gallery, horizontal-scrolling

Hi All
Thanks for reading, I couldn't explain well in my Title.

I am working on a simple flash project. In Scene 1 I have a large image above and a long scrolling image below which is a movieclip called image_slider. The Scrolling is set with actionscript 3.0 mouse over event listener. When the user moves the mouse right image_slider moves left, when mouse is left it moves right. It works very nicely. Now I wanted different parts of image_slider to change the large image above when they are clicked.

So I decided to do these actions as part of the image_slider movieclip. So I have added transparent buttons to the image_slider movie clip and added event listeners for them and functions to gotoandstop at different frames in Scene1. This works well.

My problem is that now the image_slider no longer moves freely. It does move, but as you can see it if your mouse stops moving the scrolling will stop at the next button. You have to move the mouse again to make it keep scrolling. I don't know why it has decided to do this. Does anyone have any idea of how to stop it from stopping at each button edge?

You can see the flash movie at http://www.luanamercy.com/FeatureExamples/flashgallery.html

Let me know if I can provide more information that would be helpful to you.
Maybe there is a better way to do the buttons. I am a newbie so I might be doing this a bad way.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks
Luana

Answer (score 0):

You basically lose your MOUSE_OVER Event whenever the mouse goes over one of the transparent buttons.

One way to solve it could be to have a container MovieClip that would hold both the strip and the transparent buttons and get that container to listen to your MOUSE_OVER events as opposed to the strip itself.

Comment: Oops, hit enter too soon.
So I tried creating a new movie clip and dragging my imageslider strip movie clip into it. I then changed my Actionscript so that the mouseover listener is on the container instead of the imageslider.

Comment: Wow, that's really annoying that you can't hit enter in this textbox. 
It works but it has the same problem as before. Am I not understanding what you are saying correctly? 
So when the buttons are setup with event listeners for mouse click, you think that they also have a mouseover listener? I guess that is probably how it works. And the two are interfering?

Comment: FIXED!!
After further examination of my code I thought I'd try something. I simplified the way that the listeners were setup and it works so much better now. Thanks for setting me on the right thought process Patrick!

Comment: You can check out the new version at http://www.luanamercy.com/FeatureExamples/flashgallery_2ndattempt.html
I might slow it down a little to make it easier to click.